# Hide Materialize CSS button

Tags: javascript, materialize

I would like to hide a materializeCSS button with javascript. Here is my code, but it is not hiding the button. It works in standard HTML but not when using materializeCSS.

```
<button id="btnViewJS" onclick="doStuff2()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue"><i class="material-icons left">assignment</i>View New Job Sheet</button>
<script>document.getElementById("btnViewJS").hidden=true; </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("btnViewJS").style.display='none'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `display` css style of the button to `none` like so instead:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            
<button id="btnViewJS" onclick="doStuff2(this)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small blue"><i class="material-icons left">assignment</i>View New Job Sheet</button>
<script>
  function doStuff2(elem) {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("btnViewJS").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Also this will work

```
document.getElementById("btnViewJS").style.display = "none";
```

The first one will hide the element, but keep adiacent elements fixed, the second one will render the page as the button is not present.